# How do I provide two services in an osgi.bnd file?

Tags: osgi, equinox

I'm using Equinox and I've got an OSGI.BND file which looks like this

```
Service-Component: DefaultCommunication;\
        provide:=com.whatever.service.Communication;\
        implementation:=com.whatever.myservice.DefaultCommunication
```

But now I want to provide two interfaces, Communication and Configuration.

What would the file look like then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Bnd format specification](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format#LIST):

> LIST  A comma separated list. Items should be quoted with '"' if the
>   contain commas. In general, a list item can also define attributes and
>   directives on an item.

[Bnd Service Components description](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Components):

> provide  ::= 'provide:=' LIST

In your case:

> provide:=com.whatever.service.Communication,com.whatever.service.Configuration

Comment: You may also find it a lot easier to use the bnd annotations; then you can just say `Service-Component: *` in your `.bnd` file and all of the services etc will be picked up automatically.